# How do I stop Magento to automatically add the `<pre>` tag around my custom template ?

Tags: php, magento

### Situation

- I wrote a php script, and move that script in Magento.
- In order to move it, I just simply do this in the content section on the Back-End Admin Side of Magento.

[image]

- What I noticed after that is , Magento automatically add the `<pre>` tag before my template,

[image]

and cause my view to break like this.

[image]

- I've been spending so much time trying to debug this, and I noticed when I take off the  tag, my view is `NOT` break anymore.

Result after taking off the `<pre>` tag

[image]

- How do I stop Magento to automatically add the `<pre>` tag around my custom template ?

Comment: This is not the default Magento behaviour. What else was changed?

Comment: No, just that, after taking it out, it works perfectly.

Comment: @feeela : I am all set.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the answer to this question.

Just simply click on : [image], I should see the `<pre>` tag there.
I change it to

like this :
[image]

Refresh the page and there it is, no more breaking view.

[image]